How to synchronize a global object between two threads in C++?
I have two threads, thread A and thread B, and a global object stored in a unique_ptr. Thread A initializes the object once, and thread B is designed to access the object only after the initialization is done. Here is my code:
std::unique_ptr<Object> object;
std::atomic<bool> isInitialized = false;

void createObject()
{
    object = std::make_unique<Object>();
    isInitialized = true;
}

Object& getObject()
{
    if (!isInitialized)
        assert(false);
    return *object;
}

I'm still learning about the basics of the C++ memory model so is this solution correct to begin with? If so, am I correct that the atomic variable is necessary and it needs to be present in both functions even though thread A creates the object before thread B tries to access it since otherwise the modification of object may not be visible to thread B?

thread B is designed to access the object only after the initialization is done How is that achieved? If you can guarantee that object exists every time getObject is called, then I see no need for synchronisation.

assert is usually only active in debug builds. How do you expect to behave in release build ? Is it possible that thread A didn't finish initialization and thread B already tries to access the object ?

Atomics are related to memory barrier. A memory barrier is enough to guarantee the visibility of objects between two threads. You also need to communicate here between threads thanks to a global variable. Atomics force the operation to be atomic (hence the name). C++ atomics also add memory barriers so to ensure that things modified before the atomic write are visible in other threads reading the atomic value. This is called memory ordering. Sequential consistency is the default ordering in C++ (not the fastest but safe).

Thus this is fine to me. Note however that if "thread B is designed to access the object only after the initialization is done" then, you should guarantee that using a synchronization somehow and thus the atomic does not seems needed anymore by design. In fact, in release, getObject is UB if this is not true.

@JérômeRichard I should have replaced assert with abort; the point is that the app should be killed. The question was more focused on whether the code would strictly speaking cause UB if the std::atomic was changed to a mere bool, and my understanding is that the answer is yes.

Yes a simple bool is not safe (eg. compiler can assume that no thread will change the variable and keep it in register and never reload them, simply because it is UB to communicate between threads using global variable without synchronization mechanism like atomics, locks, etc.). Note std::atomic_flag should be preferred over std::atomic<bool> (the former is guaranteed to be lock free).

@JérômeRichard: The downside of atomic_flag is that you have to use test_and_set to set it, which is a read-modify-write operation that's typically more expensive than the simple store that suffices for this program.  In this day and age, it would be a very unusual system that didn't have lock-free std::atomic<bool>.

Sorry, just let the compiler do this for you: Object& getObject() { static Object object; return object; }

@NateEldredge Good point. I though the T operator=(T desired) was implemented like for std::atomic but it isn't. Do you know why? I do not see any limitation on x86 platforms (IDK for others though it seems fine on ARM too).

@JérômeRichard: I think there was some discussion elsewhere on this site, but I can't find it now.  I believe the idea was that atomic_flag would support the absolute bare minimum of operations, just enough to implement a mutex: only test_and_set and clear.  (C++20 added test.)  I seem to recall there was an example of an obscure platform, a microcontroller or something, where test-and-set actually was the only atomic write operation supported by the hardware.

Oh, I suppose you could have atomic_flag::operator=(bool x) as if (x) test_and_set(); else clear();.  But it would obscure the fact that x = true; is actually performing a read-modify-write operation that is more expensive than you might expect of a pure store.

@ChristianStieber: That's fine if you're okay with object being allocated in static storage, and constructed unconditionally.  If it's very large and/or construction is expensive or has potentially unwanted side effects, you might want to wait and only create it if and when it's needed.

@NateEldredge You can't safely uninitialize their manual solution either, and if you look a second time you'd notice that my version only creates the object when it's first needed (unless the compiler figures out it's better to just optimize the whole thing away and setup the entire object at compile time; that's certainly possible). But rather than not using compiler features, I'd just try to add something that defeats this optimization, if it turns out to be a problem for some reason.

Create thread B from thread A after the initialization?

Your code as it stands is fine.  If getObject loads the value true from isInitialized, then it synchronizes with the store of true in createObject, because the load is acquire and the store is release (in fact, here they are both sequentially consistent, which is even stronger than necessary).  This implies that the call of make_unique and the write to object happens-before the read, so there is no data race, and the read is guaranteed to observe the new value in object and all the effects of make_unique.  And if getObject loads the value false, then (assuming that NDEBUG is not defined) it does not read from object at all, so there is no problem.
If, as suggested in comments, you were to replace std::atomic<bool> isInitialized; with simply bool isInitialized;, that would be bad.  In fact, we can forget about anything to do with object; the mere fact that the non-atomic isInitialized itself is being concurrently read and written in two different threads, is a data race all by itself, causing the program to exhibit undefined behavior.  But in particular, it wouldn't ensure synchronization, and for instance the operations on object could be reordered with those on isInitialized.
So in fact, if isInitialized were not atomic, your code would have at least three separate data races: one on isInitialized itself, one on the pointer object, and a third on the memory that object points to.  Each of these is written by createObject and read by getObject, with no synchronization whatsoever between them.
